# How to get only x results from elastic and then stop searching?

Tags: elasticsearch

My whole index is about 700M docs, this query:

```
{
  "query": {
      "term": {
         "SOME_FIELD": "SOME_TERM"
       }
  },
 "size": 10
}
```

applies to ca 5M docs. "Some_field" is indexed, not analysed. 
Query takes ca 1s on average hetzner. Too slow :) I don't care about pagination or sorting or scoring. I just want 10 first "random" matching docs.

Is there the way to do it with disabled score, in the "mysql way"?

filter or constant_score do not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option i was looking for is "terminate_after". Unfortunately it is not "very well" documemented, see:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-limit-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-count.html#_request_parameters

so, my query looks like this:

```
{
"query": {
  "term": {
     "SOME_FIELD": "SOME_TERM"
   }
},
"size": 10,
"terminate_after": 10
}
```

Don't use "10" instead of 10. Elastic does not cast it to integer and ignores the parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you go with filters, that will remove the score computation and should provide faster query speeds:

```
{
  "query": {
     "bool": {
        "filter": {
           "term": {
             "SOME_FIELD": "SOME_TERM"
           }
        }
      }   
  }
 "size": 10
}
```

If that's still too slow, you could consider using [document routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html), but it may not be a viable option for you as you might have just 1 shard or very few terms for `SOME_FIELD`.

I also suggest you go over the [production deployment](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/deploy.html) document by Elastic, it gives you an overview on how to configure your cluster optimally and can also produce some serious performance boost in case you currently have a misconfigured cluster, i.e. running on a strong machine but keeping the default `ES_HEAP_SIZE` value.

Comment: filter does not help